# Jquery ui Submit form ajax asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

Hi Guys im still learning jquery and  ajax, down below is an example of what im trying to do
but the problem is that this one is in mvc so its confusing me. 
I was just wondering if someone could refer me to an example of jquery ui popup submit form with an ajax partial post back similar to the one in the picture, in asp.net pls.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the javascript code at the end of the view file:

```
$('#form-id').submit(function () {
   data = $(this).serialize()
   $.ajax({
     url: 'your url',
     type: 'POST', 
     data: data,
     success: function(response) {
       //Implement your code here
     }
   });  
   return false;
```

});